# How can I draw the current Graphics object without clear?

Tags: c#, winforms, paint, coordinate-systems

I want to draw a function graphic using a list of points. But it is slowing down when so many points exist. So I think if I can draw without erasing current drawing I don't need to store the points. I know `Invalidate` clears the current drawing. How can I do this trick?

I an using this method currently:

```
    CoordinateSystem cos = new CoordinateSystem();
    List<PointF> points = new List<PointF>();
    float a = -20;
    void Form1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Invalidate();
    }
    void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        double x = a;
        double y = Root(x, 3);
        cos.DrawSystem(e.Graphics);
        points.Add(cos.RelativePoint(new PointF((float)x, (float)y)));
        for (int i = 1; i < points.Count - 1; i++)
        {
         e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red,points[i],points[i+1]);
        }
        a += 0.05f;

    }
```

**UPDATE**

As you suggest I have used a Bitmap to redraw. But the quality of the result is not good for me. Additionally, I have no idea how to call `Invalidate` only when the data is changed. Because here, the data changes when `Invalidate` method is called.

Code:

```
CoordinateSystem cos = new CoordinateSystem();
    Bitmap bmp;
    float a = -20;
    void Form1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Invalidate();
    }

    void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        double x = a;
        double y = Root(x, 3);
        PointF rel = cos.RelativePoint(new PointF((float)x, (float)y));
        using (Graphics grp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            grp.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            cos.DrawSystem(grp);
            grp.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, rel.X - 0.5f, rel.Y - 0.5f, 1, 1);
        }
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
        a += 0.01f;
    }
```

As you see in the result, the number texts haven't a good quality: [image]

**UPDATE 2:** Ok, I changed my code a little. Just drawing once the coordinate system at `Load` event it has a good quality now. Thanks everyone for help!

Comment: It seems you call `Invalidate()` from a Timer tick? Why would you do that. You only need to call Invalidate to trigger the form to redraw itself when the data has changed.

Comment: Draw to a bitmap, then just do a DrawImage in your paint event.  Your timer event seems unnecessary.  How do you update the graphic variables  you are using?

Comment: Yep, draw to a buffer image, then draw to your control. And don't put invalidate inside a tick event handler.

Comment: Only update the variables and the bitmap in the tick event.  The paint event should never be updating variables, it should only draw.  It looks like you keep drawing the coordinate system over itself every time — draw it only once.

Comment: The `Graphics` object does not __contain__ any graphics; it is a **tool** that lets you draw onto a related bitmap, including a control's surface.

Comment: Also: To draw a series of connected lines use the DrawLines method! (Note the plural!)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to *"not clear"* the graphics. When a `Control` needs to be drawn (has been invalidated) you have to draw everything again.

One way to improve your code a little is to use [`Graphics.DrawLines()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawlines) instead of iterating through the points and call `Graphics.DrawLine()` for each seperate line.

```
void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    double x = a;
    double y = Root(x, 3);
    cos.DrawSystem(e.Graphics);
    points.Add(cos.RelativePoint(new PointF((float)x, (float)y)));
    e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Red, points.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Paint event has a `e.ClipRectangle` property.

This is the actual rectangle that needs to be repainted, as it is not always necessary to redraw everything (e.g. part of a form is moved over your form and moved off again).

So one thing you can do is only draw the lines that fall within that rectangle.

But having said that if you are calling Invalidate, that signals that the whole things needs to be redrawn.

It would be better to keep a track of which ones you have drawn perhaps and only draw the new ones?

Comment: Worth noting that there is an overload of `Invalidate` that takes the region that needs to be redrawn as argument.